# Changed array revert back

Tags: python, arrays

My program swaps positions in an array, but they do revert back.

```
def swapPositions(list, pos1, pos2):
    list[pos1], list[pos2] = list[pos2], list[pos1]
    return list

while True:
    # Swap positions
    challanging_route = []
    rand_index = random.randint(0,len(ca)-1)
    rand_index2 = random.randint(0,len(ca)-1)
    while rand_index == rand_index2:
        rand_index2 = random.randint(0,len(ca)-1)
    challanging_route = best_route
    print("")
    print(best_route)
    a = swapPositions(challanging_route,rand_index,rand_index2)
    challanging_route = a
    if challanging_route == best_route:
        print("same ERROR")

    # Calculate distance

    distance_best = calculateDistance(cm,best_route)
    distance_challanging = calculateDistance(cm,challanging_route)
    distance_diff = distance_best - distance_challanging
    print(distance_diff)
```

I expect that I switched two positions, but I get the "same ERROR".

Comment: Hi, Kamil can you please post what error are you getting?

Comment: @adam Strauss , I think there is no error, just ``challanging_route`` and  ``best_route`` referenced to the same memory address.

Comment: Re *"challanging"*: Do you mean *"[challenging](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/challenging#Adjective)"*?

Comment: This question can't be the first of its kind. What is the canonical question for this kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a new variable to an existing list by doing

```
challanging_route = best_route
```

you are not creating a distinct copy of your existing list: if you change elements in either of the two lists (`challanging_route` or `best_route`) it will do the same change in the other one.

You probably want to actually copy your list:

```
challanging_route = best_route[:]
```

On top of that, your `swapPositions` mutates its `list` argument, which means that it actually changes the original `challanging_route` when you do `swapPositions(challanging_route,rand_index,rand_index2)`. Therefore you do not need to assign it to a new list `a`.

For clarity purposes, you should probably replace

```
a = swapPositions(challanging_route,rand_index,rand_index2)
challanging_route = a
```

with simply

```
swapPositions(challanging_route,rand_index,rand_index2)
```

Answer (score 0):

At these *lines*:

> challanging_route = best_route
>
> challanging_route = a

`best_route` and `challanging_route` reference to the same `id` in memory.

So when you change the object, ***both*** variables (in your case `challanging_route` and `best_route`) will reference the changed object.

**Memory schema addressing:**

> `best_route` --> `object at 0x9cf10c` <-- `challanging_route`

**Get memory address:**

```py
>>> hex(id(challanging_route))
out: 0x7f4f2fcc1588

>>> hex(id(best_route))
our: 0x7f4f2fcc1588
```

So you can use `copy` for a shallow copy or use `deepcopy` to copy deeper objects.

```py
import copy

challanging_route = copy.copy(best_route)
```

**Get memory address:**

```py
>>> hex(id(challanging_route))
out: 0x7f4f2fcc1588

>>> hex(id(best_route))
our: 0x7f4f2fcc1587
```

**['copy' in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)**